# Can I check in a criteriabuilder chain if value is empty?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a criteria builder chain of gets, but they can be null which means they will fail.

example:

```
predicates.add(cb.equal(house.get("adressInfo").get("streetname"),value)
```

If for example `house.get(adressInfo)` is empty I still want it returned with an empty list or just null values for everything is fine.
I only need to filter out for as an example houses with street name "A" but must also include all houses that have an empty adressInfo.

Now I get a null.streetname invalid access error because a house has an adressInfo of null

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe work around this by introducing helper methods like this:

```
private String getStreet(House house) {
    AddressInfo addressInfo = (AdressInfo) house.get("adressInfo");
    return addressInfo == null ? null : addressInfo.get("streetname");
}
```

And then you can do:

```
predicates.add(cb.equal(getStreet(house), value)
```

Comment: We are using the  @OneToMany annotations on our entities for this and thus they can be filled or be empty and the subsequent table also has a oneToMany.
i am wondering if it is better to just return the whole set and filter it in the code

Comment: Maybe you can use the isNull() / isNotNull() restrictions to filter?

Comment: I assume you mean just filter the dataset. That is indeed what i plan to do i was just wondering if it was better to let the query do the filtering for performance but it seems this is not possible unless we writ our own query which we want to avoid as that introduces its own problems